# Package Exposed by Burp Suite When using Okhttp in Android

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy, burp

is there anybody have ever got this kind of issue? I mean I have done an SSL Pinning to prevent any proxy tools such as `Charles and Burp Suite` to read the Package that I send. I have done tested in almost any possibility to encrypt the data, but when I add the certificate of burp as a system the package exposed. Is anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thank you